Hangfire - where is saved CRON in database?
Where HangFire keeps CRON for recurring job in database?
For example, how to modify such expression to get info about thier CRONs?
SELECT [Key]
      ,[Score]
      ,[Value]
      ,[ExpireAt]
      . **???** as [Cron]
FROM [HangFire].[Set]


Hangfire keeps all related data of recuring jobs in the Hash table. To select Cron Value for specific job you can use this query:
SELECT [Key]
      ,[Field]
      ,[Value]
      ,[ExpireAt]
  FROM [HangFire].[Hash] where [Key] like 'recurring-job:job-id-here' and Field = 'Cron'

[Value] would be the value of your Cron.
Key for recuring jobs in Hash table is 'recuring-job:' and Id of the job, [Field] represents description field of [Value].
Btw you can reschedule recuring job programmatically like this:
    using var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection();
    var jobData = connection.GetRecurringJobs(new List<string> { "job-id" }).FirstOrDefault();
    var recurringJobManager = new RecurringJobManager();
    recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate("job-id", jobData.Job, "cron-expression-here");

